# C++ why is `this` necessary?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, this

With GCC, we can't access the member in the base class without writing `this` explicitly, but it works on MSVC, what is going on? Is it because of the CRTP?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Base {
protected:
    T* a;
};

template<class U>
struct Derived : Base<Derived<U>> {
    void print_a() {
        std::cout << a << std::endl; // doesn't work on GCC
        std::cout << this->a << std::endl; // works on GCC
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived<float> d;
    d.print_a();
}
```

Comment: Having to use `this` is, if I recall correctly, actually mandated by the standard, MSVC is more (too?) tolerant here. Problem is that as `Base` is a template you cannot rely on `a` being available within *every* specialisation – requiring `this` then protects you from *accidentally* using a *global* `a` if the member one does *not* exist.